# Adding arrows in curves

Tags: plotting, graphics

Let's consider the following case

```
f[x_] := x^2;
data = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, -10, 10, 0.1}];
p0 = ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, Joined -> True, 
     PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}]
```

In reality my data sets correspond to closed curves (loops), for which however the analytic equation is unknown. So, the solution should not take for granted that we know the exact mathematical expression.

Now I would like to add arrows inside the curve (which is produced by joining the points) thus showing the direction (from left to right), like this

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well is a closed loop the arrows can show you if the motion along the curve is clockwise or counterclockwise. The "left to right" notation is only for this simple example!

Comment: [very closely related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43739/7167)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f, x, data];
f[x_] := x^2;
data = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, -10, 10, 0.1}];
p0 = ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}];


p0 /. Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[Table[.05, {5}]], Arrow[x]}
```

[image]

```
p0 /. Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0, .05, .05, 0}], Arrow[x]}
```

[image]

or

```
Show[p0, BaseStyle -> Arrowheads[{0, .05, .05, 0}]] /. Line -> Arrow
(* same picture *)
```

You can also set the `Arrowheads` directive as part of the `PlotStyle` option:

```
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick, Arrowheads[{0, .05, .05, 0}]}] /.  Line -> Arrow
```

or, as the setting for `BaseStyle`

```
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  BaseStyle -> Arrowheads[{0, .05, .05, 0}], PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}] /. Line -> Arrow
```

Comment: What if I want only two as in the above plot? You use arrowheads but I don't want the am the start and end of the curve.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, you can use `Arrowheads[{0, .05, .05, 0}]`.

Comment: @kglr Hi, kglr. Why the arrows are not evenly distributed? You can try `p0 /. Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[Table[.05, {30}]], Arrow[x]}`

Comment: @matheorem, good observation. I don't know why off the top of my head. This looks like a good question to post.