# Add arrow to parametric plot

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to add arrow to a simple parametric plot I'm doing:

```
F=1.85;
c=1.85;
G=0.01;
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t]==v[t], v'[t]==-v[t]+c Tanh[v[t]/F]-G Sign[x[t]],x[0]==0,v[0]==0.01},{x,v},{t,0,10}];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], v[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}]
```

I've added the arrows. There is some similar question here in the forum,
[Adding arrows in curves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60838/adding-arrows-in-curves)
 however it is not with parametric plot, and works with ListPlot, I'm new in mathematica and don't find my way with this yet, any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Your list of differential equations is bad-constructed, second item is not an equation.

Comment: @rhermans, how would you recommend to construct it?

Comment: Add an == followed by a value.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, can u post an example? maybe also address my question...

Comment: I corrected the post, now with the parametric plot ( typed a different plot before)

Comment: All I (and rhermans too) was saying is that the second term in the NDSolve, `v'[t]+c Tanh[v[t]/F]-G Sign[x[t]]` is not an equation because it doesn't have a `==`.

Comment: apologies, it's corrected now

Comment: Just add `/. Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[Table[.05, {5}]], Arrow[x]}` after the ParametricPlot (as in the accepted answer in the question you linked to). I've checked it, and it works here too.

Comment: Duplicate then.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
    F = 1.85;
c = 1.85;
G = 0.01;
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == v[t], 
    v'[t] == -v[t] + c Tanh[v[t]/F] - G Sign[x[t]], x[0] == 0, 
    v[0] == 0.01}, {x, v}, {t, 0, 10}];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], v[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}] /. 
 Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0., 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.}], Arrow[x]}
```

and play with the list under the `Arrowheads` to adjust the number and position of the arrows:

[image]

or alternatively you may use the following strategy:

```
    Show[{
  ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], v[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 1}, 
    PlotRange -> {-0.01, 0.01}] /. 
   Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0.07}], Arrow[x]},
  ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], v[t]} /. sol], {t, 1, 2}],
  ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], v[t]} /. sol], {t, 2, 3}] /. 
   Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0.07}], Arrow[x]},
  ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], v[t]} /. sol], {t, 3, 4}]
  }]
```

giving this:

[image]

Have fun!