# Adding direction arrows to discrete plot

Tags: plotting, output-formatting

I wanted a discrete plot of $y = -\dfrac{3}{2} x$ and used

```
  DiscretePlot[-3/2 x, {x, -20, 20}]
```

I do not like the vertical lines shown in the plot but I did not see an option to get rid of them.

I then did this kludge to get rid of the vertical lines

```
  ListPlot[Table[{x, -((3 x)/2)}, {x, Table[x, {x, -20, 20, 1}]}]]
```

I want to add arrowheads showing that the plot continues upward on the left and downward on the right.

I found this answer that uses [*BaseStyle*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60838/adding-arrows-in-curves), but could not figure out how to use it to place arrows at each endpoint showing direction.

```
  ListPlot[Table[{x, -((3 x)/2)}, {x, Table[x, {x, -20, 20, 1}]}], 
   BaseStyle -> Arrowheads[{-20, 30, 20, -30}], 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}] /. Line -> Arrow
```

I wanted something like this

[image]

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: The option `Filling->None` removes lines. From your text, it is not clear where you want to have the arrowheads. If it is at the axis add this option: `AxesStyle->Directive[Arrowheads[0.005]]`. If you have something else in mind, please sketch what you are after.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch:  I added an image showing the desired output. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible way could be:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
c1 = {#, -3/2 #} & /@ Range[20, 21] // N;
c2 = {#, -3/2 #} & /@ Range[-20, -21, -1] // N;

DiscretePlot[-3/2 x, {x, -20, 20}
 , Filling -> None
 , Epilog -> {
   Arrowheads[0.05], Darker@Cyan,
   Arrow[c1], Arrow[c2]
   }
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: That works for me! Somehow I missed Filling -> None. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
addArrowTips = ReplaceAll[Point[x_] :> 
    {Point[Take[x, {2, -2}]], 
     Map[Arrow] @ Extract[x, {{{2, 1}}, {{-2, -1}}}]}];
```

`addArrowTips` replaces the points at the two ends of a point list with  short arrows. We can use it as the option setting for [`DisplayFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayFunction.html) .

Alternatively, we use it as `addArrowTips @ DiscretePlot[...]` to post-process `DiscretePlot` output.

***Examples:***

```
DiscretePlot[-3/2 x, 
 {x, -20, 20}, 
 Filling -> None, 
 DisplayFunction -> addArrowTips]
```

[image]

```
DiscretePlot[{-3/2 x, x^3/100, x^2/5 + 20}, 
 {x, -20, 20}, 
 Filling -> None, 
 DisplayFunction -> addArrowTips]
```

[image]

```
DiscretePlot[{x Sin[2 x], 5 + x Cos[2 x]}, 
 {x, -6, 6, Pi/40}, 
 Filling -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium], 
 DisplayFunction -> addArrowTips]
```

[image]

Comment: I learn so much from your posts. Thank you +1.

Comment: @Moo, thank you for the upvote.